# upgrade server executable without losing user's connections

Tags: c, network-programming

I need to develop a mechanism to upgrade a running daemon in production environment to a new version without losing client's (TCP) connections. Something similar to what nginx does when you upgrade it to a new version. I need this for bug removal or to release minor version changes, which may be once a day. The daemon is developed in C for Linux platform.

The process for the upgrade would be like this:

1. The new_daemon would be ran from the command line specifying the process id of the old_daemon
2. The new_daemon would connect via socket to the old daemon to send/receive data and mesages.
3. The new_daemon would send the old_daemon a message to stop listening on the *PORT* which is used to receive client's connections. After confirming the detention of the listening service, the new_daemon would start listening on *PORT*
4. The new_daemon would send the message to old_daemon to send currently open file descriptors of the user's connections. Using the system call sendmsg() the old_daemon would pass the new_daemon all resources it has allocated with the kernel, not only the connections, but also all open files.
5. The new_daemon would send the message to old_daemon to pass all global memory variables and the old_daemon would send it over the socket connection between both processes.

This process is very complex, so I would like to ask if someone can suggest a better process or maybe there is some methodology to do this easily? The goal is to have the least downtime during the upgrade process.

TIA

Answer (score 1):

Another alternative is to force the `old_daemon` to `fork()/exec()` the `new_daemon` and immediately stop accepting. The `new_daemon` would inherit the listening socket, existing connections, and open files (unless they are `fcntl`'d to `FD_CLOEXEC`) automagically.

That said, I don't think there is a clean way to hand over incomplete jobs (as I understand steps 4 and 5 try to accomplish). If possible, let the `old_daemon` complete them.

Comment: Thanks, this is an excellent way to copy the file descriptors. +1 for that.

Answer (score 0):

One alternative is to write most of your demon as a shared library and use dlopen to link the new functions  into the running process. This means some parts can't be changed and you might have concurrency issues but it removes the need for IPC.

Comment: I agree, this is the cheapest (in term of development times) alternative. Maybe i will go for it. But this only works if the data structure (variables) doesn't change. So, your suggestion is VERY good, something i didn't thought of, but it is still 50% of the solution.